# When compiling Boost.Python in debug mode, I encountered an error indicating the absence of python.lib

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

Here's the translation of the provided text:

I want to compile Boost.Python's debug version on Windows using VS2019. When I tried to compile, it told me that the python.lib file was missing, but it should be Python_d.lib.

I tried something out: I replaced python_d.lib with python.lib, and the compilation passed. So, it means that during debug, python_d.lib wasn't used.

> I obtained the code from the Boost Git repository and configured it using CMake GUI. I enabled the Python build options and compiled the dynamic library.

I'm quite confused and unsure whether I should use python_d.lib or python.lib.

How should I correctly compile Boost.Python?